# How to convert a list of numbers to a refromatted string

Tags: python

How to convert a list of numbers to a refromatted string.

I am new to the list and have seen simple Python type programming that can be executed in a simple text editor.

I have a List of numbers and would like to convert to list to a string of number with some additions.

i.e.

```
numbers

1234
1235
1236
1237
```

change to:

```
"1234.ARD" "1235.ARD" "1236.ARD" "1237.ARD"
```

If this is at all possible please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) and a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
In [1]: numbers = [1234, 1235, 1236, 1237]

In [2]: ['%s.ARD' % n for n in numbers]
Out[2]: ['1234.ARD', '1235.ARD', '1236.ARD', '1237.ARD']
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want the output to be isn't exactly clear (is it a list of strings or a single string?).

Regardless, I'll give both solutions and you can pick whichever you want:

```
>>> lst = [1234, 1235, 1236, 1237]
>>> print (["{}.ARD".format(x) for x in lst]) # List of strings
['1234.ARD', '1235.ARD', '1236.ARD', '1237.ARD']
>>>
>>> print (" ".join(['"{}.ARD"'.format(x) for x in lst])) # Single string
"1234.ARD" "1235.ARD" "1236.ARD" "1237.ARD"
>>>
```

The important concepts here are:

1. A [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
2. [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)
3. [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Comment: solution No 3 - `" ".join(map(lambda x: '%s.ARD' % x, number))`